# How to change HttpContext.Response

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I want that my api all the time returns the same model something like this:

```
result {
    body: "body",
    error: {
        message: "message",
        StatusCode: "stasusCode"
        }
    }
```

My any controller returns some model. For example:

```
model: {
    field1: "field1",
    field2: "field2"
    }
```

I want that a middleware generate the model like this if we have successful:

```
result {
    body: {
        field1: "field1",
        field2: "field2"
        }
    error: null
    }
```

So how I should change response body?
If we dont have successful I implemented like this:

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
                {
                    response = new RequestModel
                    {
                        Error = new ErrorModel
                        {
                            Message = error.Message,
                            StatusCode = error.Code
                        },
                        Body= null
                    }
                });

                await response.WriteAsync(result);
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably a custom error handling middleware. You can create something like below code to override response or have a look [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/01/17/net-6-global-error-handler-tutorial-with-example#:%7E:text=NET%20Global%20Error%20Handler%20Middleware,pipeline%20section%20of%20the%20Program.) to see how you can create it as you like.

```
    public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> _logger;    
        public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("message to log before handling the exception", e);
                await HandleException(context, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleException(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        var responseObject = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
            {
                response = new RequestModel
                {
                    Error = new ErrorModel
                    {
                        Message = error.Message,
                        StatusCode = error.Code
                    },
                    Body= null
                }
            });

        var exceptionData = var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseObject );

        _logger.LogError(exception.ToString()); // log exception if you need

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"; // set content type
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // status code you want to return
        await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(exceptionData, 0, exceptionData.Length, CancellationToken.None);
    }
```